# jquery years months and days variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

when the system appears, I see that it is very complicated, but I have a problem, I found this code from somewhere, but I am writing because I do not have much knowledge, thank you in advance to those who help.

http://jsfiddle.net/8qbjh3z2/

```js
function dateAgo(date) {  

    var startDate = new Date( date + " " + '12:00 AM');
    var endDate = new Date();

    var diffDate  = new Date(new Date() - startDate);

    var yearDiff  = diffDate.toISOString().slice(0, 4) - 1970;
    var monthDiff = diffDate.getMonth(); 
    var dayDiff   = diffDate.getDate()-1;

    var msec  = endDate - startDate;
    var mins  = Math.floor(msec / 60000);
    var hrs   = Math.floor(mins / 60);
    var days  = Math.floor(hrs / 24);
      
    var label = 'Posted ';
    if( mins <= 30 ){
        label += ' Just Now';
    }else if( hrs <= 24 ){
        label += ' Just Today';
    }else{
        if( yearDiff > 0  ){
            label += ( yearDiff > 1 ) ? yearDiff+' years, ' : yearDiff+' year, ';
        }

        if( monthDiff > 0 ){
            label += ( monthDiff > 1 ) ? monthDiff+' months, ' : monthDiff+' month, ';
        }

        if( dayDiff > 0 ){
            label += ( dayDiff > 1 ) ? dayDiff+' days ' : dayDiff+' day ';
        }

        label += 'ago';
    }
  
    return label;   
    
}

(function() {
    var elements = document.body.getElementsByClassName('iso-date');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var date  = elements[i].innerHTML;
        var label = dateAgo(date);
        elements[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML = label;   
    }
})();
```

```html
<div class="iso-date">2019-09-30</div>
<div class="display-date"></div>
```

The codes in the above code file are like this. The system I want to be done automatically adds the month, year or day when the date is changed. I want the week part to be added as an extra. If it is something that is not seen in the system, I want the system to be added in the class and id section that I have specified. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To get the best results here you should show what you have tried, errors that you are getting, etc.   Take a minute and read over stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. After you read that over, come back and update your question with more details and code that you are using that is not working. As it stands currently you are basically asking to have the work done for you as opposed to asking for help solving a specific problem you are having.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a wrong explanation. Since I'm new to the site, I had to read with rules at first, actually I want help. I can't resolve for 3 days

Comment: Use `var startDate = new Date( date + 'T00:00:00');` instead to fix the error

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getAge(dateString) {
  var now = new Date();
  var today = new Date(now.getYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate());

  var yearNow = now.getYear();
  var monthNow = now.getMonth();
  var dateNow = now.getDate();

  var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6,10),
                     dateString.substring(0,2)-1,                   
                     dateString.substring(3,5)                  
                     );

  var yearDob = dob.getYear();
  var monthDob = dob.getMonth();
  var dateDob = dob.getDate();
  var age = {};
  var ageString = "";
  var yearString = "";
  var monthString = "";
  var dayString = "";


  yearAge = yearNow - yearDob;

  if (monthNow >= monthDob)
    var monthAge = monthNow - monthDob;
  else {
    yearAge--;
    var monthAge = 12 + monthNow -monthDob;
  }

  if (dateNow >= dateDob)
    var dateAge = dateNow - dateDob;
  else {
    monthAge--;
    var dateAge = 31 + dateNow - dateDob;

    if (monthAge < 0) {
      monthAge = 11;
      yearAge--;
    }
  }

  age = {
      years: yearAge,
      months: monthAge,
      days: dateAge
      };

  if ( age.years > 1 ) yearString = " years";
  else yearString = " year";
  if ( age.months> 1 ) monthString = " months";
  else monthString = " month";
  if ( age.days > 1 ) dayString = " days";
  else dayString = " day";


  if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + ", " + age.months + monthString + ", and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
    else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) );
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0))
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " and " + age.months + monthString + " old.";
 
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString ;
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months > 0))
    ageString = age.months + monthString + " old.";
  else ageString = "Oops! Could not calculate age!";

  return ageString;
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += "<br />" + (getAge('02/09/2019'));
```

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
```

There was a solution in this way, but I could not do this. The system, for example: 2 years, 11 months, and 30 days old. gives. I want the registration date in the system to be 1 year and 2 months after 1 year, so I cannot cancel the number of days.